# Google sheets: Count all value where condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to count how many "products" appear in my tables with the same value

I made this little example to explain what I want:

[image]

Values excepted (only the count):

- Apple with value 1 = **2** (count)
- Apple with value 2 = **1** (count)
- Banana with value 4 = **2** (count)
- Banana with value 1 = **1** (count) **...**

As you can see, I want to count how many "Apple" has value 1 in my two tables, how many "Apple" has value 2 etc...

With Google Sheets, I know how to count, but not how to get the value in the right cell.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dsby2YS_x5W8-QqoTqzckPUPo1rxuB5_s7ZE3GXdEAc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dsby2YS_x5W8-QqoTqzckPUPo1rxuB5_s7ZE3GXdEAc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A3:A&" "&B3:B; C3:C&" "&D3:D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1)
  where Col1 <> ' '
  group by Col1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Very simple solution :)

Comment: @player0, is it possible to come back in my Google Sheet? I'm trying to make an other query similar to yours

Comment: @Naografix it is recommended to post a new question regarding your new case.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

There might be a better or more practical solution but I will keep it simple.

- My approach would be to get the data of both tables into a single column so it will be feasible to count the pairs.
- The first step is to concatenate the index and the value columns and then flatten the resulting columns into one.

### Solution:

I am going to use two formulas.

In my example, cell `F1` has the main formula:

`=flatten({ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A7&"  "&B2:B7), ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C7&"  "&D2:D7)})`

And cell `G1` has the count formula:

`=arrayformula(if(F1:F<>"",countif($F1:$F,F1:F),""))`

### Result:

[image: result]